# How to get the URL of image from the img tag that is present as a value of a key in an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value, imageurl

I've an associative array titled `$data` as follows :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 170
            [item_title] => Master of Engineering
            [item_time_stamp] => 1421152531
            [item_user_id] => 244
            [item_type_id] => pages
            [item_photo] => 169
[profile_image] => <img src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/pages/category_169.jpg"  alt=""  width="50"  height="50" />
)
[1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 169
            [item_title] => SF
            [item_time_stamp] => 1421063963
            [item_user_id] => 901
            [item_type_id] => pages
[profile_image] => <img src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/pages/category_169.jpg"  alt=""  width="50"  height="50" />
        )
)
```

Now I want to get only the URL of image in the key `[profile_image]`. The final resulting array should look like follows :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 170
            [item_title] => Master of Engineering
            [item_time_stamp] => 1421152531
            [item_user_id] => 244
            [item_type_id] => pages
            [item_photo] => 169
[profile_image] => http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/pages/category_169.jpg
)
[1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 169
            [item_title] => SF
            [item_time_stamp] => 1421063963
            [item_user_id] => 901
            [item_type_id] => pages
[profile_image] => http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/pages/category_169.jpg
        )
)
```

How should I get this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

try this, its a bit crapy but it works normaly

```
for ($i = 0; isset($data[$i]); $i++){
$temp = explode("\"", $data[$i]['profile_image']);
$data[$i]['profile_image'] = $temp[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this :

```
//to test
$data = array(
    array(
        'profile_image'=>'<img src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/pages/category_169.jpg"  alt=""  width="50"  height="50" />'
    ),
    array(
        'profile_image'=>'<img src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/pages/category_169.jpg"  alt=""  width="50"  height="50" />'
    )
);

function fixdata($data){
    $fix = function($url){
        $patt = "/h\S*.jpg|.gif|.png/";
        preg_match($patt,$url,$match); 
        return (empty($match[0]))?$url:$match[0];
    };
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        $data[$key]['profile_image'] = $fix($value['profile_image']);
    }
    return $data;
}
var_dump($data);
$newdata = fixdata($data);
var_dump($newdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will build a new array and allow you to scrape the contents of any value from one of the nested arrays. What I have written will work for the case where your img tags are always in the same format, however if you run into the case where you have different formats, you can modify the area where the code is scraping the tag to rebuild the url with minimal effort.

```
$mainArray = array(

    array(
        'item_id'           => 170,
        'item_title'        => 'Master of Engineering',
        'item_time_stamp'   => 1421152531,
        'item_user_id'      => 244,
        'item_type_id'      => 'pages',
        'item_photo'        => 169,
        'profile_image'     => '<img src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/pages/category_169.jpg"  alt=""  width="50"  height="50" />'
    ),
    array(
        'item_id'           => 169,
        'item_title'        => 'SF',
        'item_time_stamp'   => 1421063963,
        'item_user_id'      => 901,
        'item_type_id'      => 'pages',
        'item_photo'        => 169,
        'profile_image'     => '<img src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/pages/category_169.jpg"  alt=""  width="50"  height="50" />'
    )

);


$newArray = array();
foreach($mainArray as $innerArray){


    $newInnerArray = array();
    foreach($innerArray as $key => $val){

        if($key !== 'profile_image'){

            $newInnerArray[$key] = $val; 

        } else {

            //Scrape the url here
            $link = strstr($val, '"');
            $link = strstr($link, ' alt', TRUE);
            $link = str_replace('"', '', $link);
            $link = str_replace(' ', '', $link);

            $newInnerArray[$key] = $link;

        }        

    }

    $newArray[] = $newInnerArray;

}

echo '<pre>';

echo var_export($newArray, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the DOCDocument class:

```
foreach ($data as &$item) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($item["profile_image"]);
    $item["profile_image"] = $doc->documentElement->getAttribute("src");
}
```

thus you are not dependent on the detailed format of your IMG string, like where your src attribute is.